# Capistrano's 'cap staging deploy' tasks complete successfully but changes don't appear on staging server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, repository, capistrano

This is baffling because I've properly updated and pushed to GIT's master branch before running 'cap staging deploy' but the changes just don't render on the staging server.

Please let me know if I can provide more info that may be helpful.

Thanks in advance for any help.

The app is restarting successfully the deploy too:

```
INFO [907b2583] Running /usr/bin/env touch /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/current/tmp/restart.txt as deploy@x.x.x.x
DEBUG [907b2583] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.1 /usr/bin/env touch /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/current/tmp/restart.txt )
INFO [907b2583] Finished in 0.666 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

Edit:  The deploy script is set to the correct branch, however the source code in /views doesn't match local source.

Edit:  The correct source is in the git repo master branch.  This seems to suggest my deploy is pulling from a different fork than intended.

Edit:  Capistrano deploy log excerpt pertaining to GIT:

```
DEBUG Uploading /home/deploy/deploy_tmp/myappme_app/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
INFO Uploading /home/deploy/deploy_tmp/myappme_app/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
INFO [ffabbafb] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /home/deploy/deploy_tmp/myappme_app/git-ssh.sh as deploy@x.x.x.x
DEBUG [ffabbafb] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.1 /usr/bin/env chmod +x /home/deploy/deploy_tmp/myappme_app/git-ssh.sh )
INFO [ffabbafb] Finished in 0.640 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [16e6d3cd] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:CryptoWhippet/myappme_app.git as deploy@x.x.x.x
DEBUG [16e6d3cd] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.1 GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/home/deploy/deploy_tmp/myappme_app/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:CryptoWhippet/myappme_app.git )
DEBUG [16e6d3cd]        2cd85c80e2d9b4c33b791c341dd19894        refs/heads/master
INFO [16e6d3cd] Finished in 5.960 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

[..]

DEBUG [4341e870] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo/HEAD ] as deploy@x.x.x.x
DEBUG [4341e870] Command: [ -f /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo/HEAD ]
DEBUG [4341e870] Finished in 0.691 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO The repository mirror is at /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo
DEBUG [20a36e89] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@x.x.x.x
DEBUG [20a36e89] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [20a36e89] Finished in 0.648 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [6bb0fabc] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update as deploy@x.x.x.x
DEBUG [6bb0fabc] Command: cd /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.1 GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/home/deploy/deploy_tmp/myappme_app/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git remote update )
DEBUG [6bb0fabc]        Fetching origin
INFO [6bb0fabc] Finished in 4.061 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [bcc4ff25] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@x.x.x.x
DEBUG [bcc4ff25] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [bcc4ff25] Finished in 0.648 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [a3663844] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/releases/20151209132220 as deploy@x.x.x.x
DEBUG [a3663844] Command: cd /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.1 GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/home/deploy/deploy_tmp/myappme_app/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/releases/20151209132220 )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
INFO [a3663844] Finished in 0.650 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [b2cf939e] Running /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -f - -C /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/releases/20151209132220 as deploy@x.x.x.x
DEBUG [b2cf939e] Command: cd /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.1 GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/home/deploy/deploy_tmp/myappme_app/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -f - -C /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/releases/20151209132220 )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
INFO [b2cf939e] Finished in 3.266 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [b21a4932] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@x.x.x.x
DEBUG [b21a4932] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [b21a4932] Finished in 0.646 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [efdb30ab] Running /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 --abbrev-commit master as deploy@x.x.x.x
DEBUG [efdb30ab] Command: cd /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.1 GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/home/deploy/deploy_tmp/myappme_app/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 --abbrev-commit master )
DEBUG [efdb30ab]        8b9d346
DEBUG [efdb30ab] Finished in 0.630 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

Comment: can you show the cap trace. it must be missing to restart server.

Comment: @Nithin, I had thought the same thing, but it is restarting.  I have even manually restarted.  Will add the info above.

Comment: expected branch is being set in deploy script? manually check the soruce code on server once.

Comment: @Nithin, Interesting!  The correct branch is set in the deploy script (left as default), but manually checking the source on the server shows the code in /views doesn't match my local code.

Comment: @Nithin, Now also noted:  the correct source is in the git repo master branch.  This seems to suggest my deploy is pulling from a different fork than intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug with some version of sass-rails that weren't recompiling stylesheets on deploy. You should first check if the git directory on your staging server is the same as in master, then check if functionality you added is working. If so, and you have only issues with stylesheets or maybe javascript and you probably need to play with gem versions.

To find working gem version you may manually change gemfile on staging server, then use same command as capistrano uses for bundle and precompiling assets.

If it doesnt help, check the cloned (by capistrano) repository mirror to confirm it's in the same state as origin/maser.  If it doesn't match, and you're sure the git repository setting in your deploy configuration is correct, you should purge the repository directory and re-run your deploy routine.

Comment: Hi, Yeah I remember that but this is different.  Even the erb files in app/views/ aren't updating.  The deploy script refers to the correct .git and branch, but somehow it appears to be pulling from a different fork.

Comment: Try to repeat capistrano commands one by one, it may give you hint on what went wrong. Have you checked if it's actually does a release in releases folder? it may not updated "current" symlink. If you check it using ssh, you may see the old folder. `cd .. && cd current` to make sure you reviewing same folder where "current" symlink is looking at.

Comment: I like your thinking, I just did exactly that... checked the actual /release to make sure it matched what i was seeing in /current, and it does. :)

Comment: Without seeing the log, i guess executing commands one by one should show you what went wrong. Have you reviewed if it actually pulls out right source to git? i dont remember exactly where capistrano stores git copy, but you may clearly see what command it executes for that, try to execute that command and check if git sources are the same as on master. If no, then capistrano pulls out wrong git sources. If yes, then capistrano fails at copy. I personally never experienced such issue but it should be easy to figure where it fails.

Comment: I can't see any indication of it failing in the log.  I have updated the post with 'cap staging deploy' log info relating to GIT.

Comment: `The repository mirror is at /var/www/my_app/my_app-stgng/repo` you probably should check if it's in the same state as origin/master.

Comment: Thank you!  It is different!  It refers to a previous fork.  Shall I just update the name in /repo/config and rerun the deployment?

Comment: You should remove that directory and make sure capistrano fetch master branch. If it doesn't, i would check deploy config and check why it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you @Fedcomp!  Removing the /repo directory solved the problem.  Please edit your question so I can Accept. :)

Comment: I edited your answer to reflect the solution you helped me deduce. Once peer reviewed I will accept it.  Thanks @Fedcomp.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your server or not?

there are couple of things which we need to do after deployment once you deploy the code we need to checkout the server and we need to restart the server instance so that the changes should be come up your staging server, hopefully this may help you.

might be you need to add some task at your staging configuration file so that the server should be restated automatically if you want to restart the automatically.

```
after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
```

Comment: Yes, it restarts.  I've updated the post to reflect this.